# How to count specific items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got this array in my jquery Script :

[image]

I want to count all items inside my array called `div.item.bloc-membre`

Right now I have this code that returns me *75*

`console.log($(response).length);`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: filter.......... https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: `$(response).filter("div.item.bloc-membre").length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
console.log($(response).filter("div.item.bloc-membre").length);
```